# GroupBy timestamp interval in JOOQ

Tags: spring, postgresql, kotlin, jooq

I want to group timestamps by a period of time. 


**EDIT PROBLEM - CHANGE CONCEPT**

I prepare SQL:

```
SELECT s.start_interval, s.end_interval, count(a.create_time)
FROM (
   SELECT start_interval, start_interval + ((b.close_date - b.open_date) / 5) AS end_interval
   FROM b_table b
     JOIN generate_series(b.open_date, b.close_date, (b.close_date - b.open_date) / 5) start_interval ON (1=1)
   WHERE b.id = 1
 ) AS s
 LEFT JOIN a_table a ON (a.create_time >= s.start_interval and a.create_time < s.end_interval and a.b_table_id = 1)
GROUP BY s.start_interval, s.end_interval;
```

**(magic number 5 means intervals)**

Result of my SQL:

[image]

How can I resolve this problem in JOOQ (for example generateSeries is not supports)?

Comment: What's not working?

Comment: I have a problem with the sum. Because I choose two intervals but i get four separate result:

    "example": [
        {
            "sum": 1,
            "interval": 1528588800
        },
        {
            "sum": 1,
            "interval": 1528588800
        },
        {
            "sum": 1,
            "interval": 1528934400
        },
        {
            "sum": 1,
            "interval": 1528934400
        }
    ]

I also change count() -> count().`as`("sum"),

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand what you're trying to do. Can you give some example input and expected output data?

Comment: I would like to achieve the same as in this case: 

https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/57582/group-by-timestamp-interval-10-minutes-postgresql/127874
But instead of the ready interval as there (600 seconds) I want to calculate it on the basis of my formula, which I gave at the beginning of post

Comment: It would really be much easier if you just showed concrete examples directly on your question, rather than making an analogy to some "similar" question

Comment: Ok i prepare an example and edit post

Comment: @LukasEder I hope that everything is clear now

Comment: Problem was resolved by similar code.

Comment: Glad to hear that! You can answer your own questions here on Stack Overflow, if you like. I'm sure it might help someone visiting this question in the future.